# what's the difference between including a parameter name in a function declaration and not including one?

Tags: c++, function, declaration

I remember reading before about the significance (or lack thereof) between including a parameter name in a function declaration and not including one. But I can't remember what it was that I read or where I read it.

for example,

```
void do_something(int *); // No parameter name included, only type.
```

vs...

```
void do_something(int * i); // type AND parameter name included.
```

So what's the difference between these two declarations? Thanks for reading and maybe answering this possibly trivial question.

-- UPDATE --

Okay, so the thing I had read was a set of style guidelines from an old professor of mine warning against including a parameter name in function definition and NOT using the parameter in the function.

```
void do_something(int * i) { //code that doesn't use i;} //BAD
void do_something(int *) { //code that doesn't use i;} //OK
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no difference, as far as the compiler is concerned.

Adding meaningful parameter names is a helpful form of documentation, though.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the second version could be more readable if you choose a good parameter name. Nothing more to say ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical difference between those declarations.  If you instead had

```
void accumulate_stats(int * count);
```

or something similarly descriptive, it would be an improvement in self-documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In a forward declaration, there should be no difference.  They will both describe the same memory layout for the call, so they should be completely interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

For a forward declaration, it doesn't make any difference.

In the actual definition, a parameter without a name isn't checked for use.  It's a way to have unused parameters without some UNUSED_PARAM(x) macro or some other trickery whose only purpose is to shut the compiler up about it.

Comment: Macros are sort of evil, what with name collisions, multiple evaluations of args, etc. Sometimes they're practically necessary, but it's a good idea to avoid them in general. So, better use function template `unusedParam`. That is, if you can't live with the warnings. Cheers,

Comment: Agreed, macros are evil.  But IMO, any code that exists only to say "yeah, i'm not doing anything with this argument.  Shut up, you stupid compiler!" isn't much better.

Comment: Which is why the `(void)argName;` syntax exists. That tells the compiler that `argName` is "used", though it evaluates to a no-op.

Comment: @Jonathan: Again, *any* extra code whose only purpose is to shut the compiler up, is pretty ugly IMO.  Why name the variable at all if you're not going to use it?

Comment: @cHao: I'm not disagreeing. Just saying--there *is* a standard syntax for this particular warning-dodge, so there's no need for a macro.

Comment: @Jonathan: `(void) arg;` isn't immediately obvious as to what it does.  It's not even obvious to the untrained eye that it'd work at all.  Hence why people turn to macros and `unusedParam` templates and such.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "real declaration", it is called a *definition*. And what many people refer to as a "forward declaration" is really just a plain declaration.

Comment: @Fred: Thanks...i'm forever mixing up "declaration" and "definition"...  :P

Comment: @cHao: What's your point? I'm just saying there's a standard syntax. I didn't say it was pretty. It's also not immediately obvious what `void *(** t)(int (* tc)(double, struct tm *))` does. Or even what `&value` does, to a neophyte. C has weird syntax.

Comment: @Jonathan: My point is, that's *not* "standard syntax".  It works because of how statements are defined and translated.  The "standard syntax", AFAIK in C++, is not to name the args at all.  That's the only syntax that gets explicit mention in my (draft) copy of the standards, anyway.  (8.4:6)  And BTW, the question is tagged C++, not C.

Comment: @cHao: That may be your point, but stamping your feet isn't going to make it accurate. Firstly, the C++ standard implies certain things without stating them explicitly. The standard does not say that `7 + 9` will evaluate to `16`, but it does, because it's an implied behaviour based on the written portion of the standard. The same goes for the behaviour of a statement such as `(void)arg;`. Secondly, when I say "C has weird syntax", it is implied that C++, which inherits almost all of that syntax, also has weird syntax. You're coming off as trying to pick a fight. Relax. :)

Comment: @Jonathan: No hostility intended.  I can just be pretty stubborn when i believe i'm right.  :)  As for `7 + 9`, though...a better analogue here would be `7 + 9;`, which (like `(void)arg;`) is an expression as a statement.  It compiles.  It might even run(!), and if it did, then yes, it'd end up evaluating to 16.  But one won't know without disassembling, because the "statement" has no side effect, unless it's the last statement in a function.  A stupid (but standards-compliant) compiler might actually translate it to machine code, though, and it'd be totally within its rights to do so.